# Organizing configuration for publishing images created via TikZ inline code

Tags: org-mode, config

I use Emacs + org-mode to maintain my website.

Here some related parts of [my configuration](https://github.com/larsen/emacs-configuration):

```
(defvar personal-website-remote-directory-prefix "/ssh:***:/srv/www/stefanorodighiero.net/")
(defun personal-website-remote-absolute-directory (directory)
  (concat personal-website-remote-directory-prefix directory))

(setq org-publish-project-alist
  `(
    ("website" 
     :components ("website-pages" "website-images"))

    ("website-pages"
     :base-directory "/home/larsen/www/stefanorodighiero.net/"
     :base-extension "org"
     :exclude "posts"
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     :publishing-directory ,(personal-website-remote-absolute-directory "/")
     :recursive t
     :html-preamble ,personal-website-navigation-header
     )

    ("website-images"
     :base-directory "/home/larsen/www/stefanorodighiero.net/images/"
     :base-extension "png\\|jpg\\|JPG\\|gif"
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     :recursive t
     :publishing-directory ,(personal-website-remote-absolute-directory "images/")
     )
```

A couple of things in particular are important in the context of this
question:

- `website-pages` is **any org file** that is found looking recursively in
  my website directory tree. To publish them I use
  `org-html-publish-to-html`
- `website-images` have to in the `images/` directory to be copied to the
  production site. When I need to add a image in a page, I put the
  file in `images/`, and I **manually** add a `file:../images/...` link in 
  the org file (with the appropriate number of `../` in front of it,
  depending on where the org file is). This is not ideal but it worked
  acceptably for the amount of content I produce.

Now, I'd like to use [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) to produce graphics to be included in my pages.  After some experiments, I've settled on adding these instructions to the pages where I want to include inline TikZ snippets.

```
#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
```

It works well when I ask a preview (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>): the image files
produced by TikZ + [convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) are put in the directory configured in
`org-preview-latex-image-directory` (default is `ltximg`, so a
**relative** path).

When I want to publish the page, on the other hand, the images
are ignored because they're not under `images/`, nor they are
`org` files to be considered for publication.

I could configure `org-preview-latex-image-directory` to put the
images in the `images/` directory: I think publishing would work, but
local preview would not.

How could I organize the configuration to have automatic preview and
publication in my workflow?

Comment: And what about making the directory `org-preview-latex-image-directory` to be a symbolic or hard link to `images` ?